# SQL query to update field

Tags: mysql

I need to update 3 fields in a mySQL database table programmaticaly. I need to update `label_id, label & company_id`

What I need is an SQL query that allows me to indicate what the `company_id` is and the "label" fields and then have it generate the label ids automatically.

For example, create `label="test"`, `company_id="17"`......and have it automatically generate the label_id. Any ideas on an sql query to do this? Table structure example:

```
label_id      label       company_id  
1             Cook        8  
2             Chef        8  
3             Driver      9
```

Comment: `UPDATE yourtable SET field=value, field=value WHERE field=value`?

Comment: Thanks. But how will it know to create the label_id values?

Comment: Maybe use a trigger on insert.  Once the first two values are inserted you could then generate and insert the company_id, possibly based off of the first two values:  Cook  8  Cook_8 (or Cook8, C8, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're needing the `label_id` to be generated automatically, it sounds like you're talking about an `INSERT` rather than an actual `UPDATE`

`INSERT INTO table_name(label, company_id) VALUES ("Company", 5)`

This would require your table to be created, such as:

```
CREATE table_name (label_id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, label VARCHAR(255), company_id INT)
```

Comment: Agree with Rawkode.  Also, your company_id value should be a foreign key tied to the Primary key of the Company table.